# Cannot input password when installing mariadb on centos

Tags: centos7, mariadb

After following the commands below, I get this error. At this point, it doesn't allow me to input a password - no key apart from Enter works. Enter just gives me this same error. How do I set a password now?

I'm on Cent OS 7, by the way.

```
# sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
# sudo systemctl enable mariadb.service
# sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MariaDB, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none):
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Enter current password for root (enter for none):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are locked out. You can reset the MariaDB password using the below steps:

1. Stop MySQL

```
sudo systemctl stop mariadb
```

2. Start the database without loading the grant tables or enabling networking:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

3. Now you can connect to the database as the root user, which should not ask for a password.

```
mysql -u root
```

4. You should enter the mysql prompt now. Now we can actually change the MariaDB root password.

For MySQL 5.7.6 and newer as well as MariaDB 10.1.20 and newer, use the following command.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

For MySQL 5.7.5 and older as well as MariaDB 10.1.20 and older, use:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

Make sure to replace new_password with your new password of choice.

Once done, Restart MySQL. You should be able to login with the new password.

Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me!